# Excel function =isnumber(search *)) not working as expected

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I running formula =ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2,$A3)), the output is true. Cell B2= "Red" and "Red" appears in cell A3. The condition is TRUE.

This formula fails when cell E2 is blank. There are no spaces or hidden characters.

Why is `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E$2,$A3))` returning `True`?

[image]

Comment: Does excel assume a blank or empty cell is 0? Try adding a test fro isblank()

Comment: `Search` on  a blank cell to a populated cell will return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first check if `E2` is blank and then proceed with `ISNUMBER` if true

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E$2), FALSE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E$2,$A3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`SEARCH` will interpret blanks as empty strings.

Another approach to what it looks like you're trying to do is to replace the substring with an empty string and see if the length changes:

```
=LEN($A2)>LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,E$1,""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, two variations, one as per the other answer but the other using find().

[image]

For the first, it returns a blank.
For the second with find() then iferror will deal with the value error.